Dart format for CI/CD pipelines
Is there a way to configure the line length for the Dart formatter?
I'm currently using a custom settings.json file in VSCode with the line length set to 120 for a Flutter project, and it works correctly. However, when I apply the Dart formatter for a CI/CD pipeline, it resets the code to 80 characters per line, modifying all my files to match this line length again.
How can I make the Dart formatter adhere to the 120-character line length setting?

You can use dart format --line-length=120.  I don't know why that option currently is not listed by dart format --help.

The flag --line-length=120 does the job. Thanks @jamesdlin

The omission from dart format --help is tracked in https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/54146.
